# Which Android UX top navigation element is Facebook using?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, bottomnavigationview

Please check the below screenshots I have taken from `facebook` and `dropbox paper`, and in particular the section I have circled in red.

Are those `tabs` or `BottomNavigationView` used in top somehow or some other UI element? However notice how they contain a section at the right end to open a navigation drawer as well! From the other end, you can swipe between view, which is the behavior of tabs!

Anyway I noticed these really don't contain more than 5 items, which is the limit for `BottomNavigationView`.

FaceBook photo

[image]

Dropbox paper photo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is basically Tab view with 4 fragments inside them.
 The other thing is instagram and facebook is developed in react native not is java code so they are using there own views to do this task. I believe it is not really difficult to build this UI.

Hope this will help you.